# Bi-holomorphic function from $D(0,1)$ to $\{z;1<|z|<R\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Do bi-holomorphic function exists from $D(0,1)=\{z;|z|<1\}$ to $\{z;1<|z|<R\}$?

Comment: You might want to add a definition of bi-holomorphic function.

Answer (score 5):

No. The disk $D(0, 1)$ is simply-connected. The annulus $\{z \in \Bbb C \mid 1 < |z| < R\}$ is not.

Comment: Oh, yes. Then can we find a covering map from $\{z;|z|<1\}$ to $\{z;1<|z|<R\}$? I need this to construct the Poncare metric of $\{z;1<|z|<R\}$.

Comment: @XLDD You can construct a covering map from the upper half-plane to the annulus using the complex logarithm. Then you apply the Riemann mapping theorem to get the map you want. This is probably better suited for a new question.

Comment: Year. I know that $e^{iz}$ maps the upper half plane to the unit disk without center. However, how can I construct a map onto $B_R$?

Comment: Year. I have got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @XLDD You're welcome. Reading my comment again, the Riemann mapping theorem is an overkill for mapping the unit disk onto the upper half-plane biholomorphically, but you get the idea.

Comment: I got that $$\frac{\frac{e^{\pi i}}{z^{\ln R}}-i}{\frac{e^{\pi i}}{z^{\ln R}}-i}$$ maps $B_R$ to the unit disk. Is it true?